# Bagofwords no attribute precision and recall

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributes, nltk, precision

```
import os


ENGLISH_OPINION_LEXICON_LOCATION = os.path.join('opinion-lexicon-English')
```

POS_WORDS_FILE = os.path.join(ENGLISH_OPINION_LEXICON_LOCATION, 'positive-words.txt')
    NEG_WORDS_FILE = os.path.join(ENGLISH_OPINION_LEXICON_LOCATION, 'negative-words.txt')

## pos_words = [({'amazing': True}, 'positive'), ({'great': True}, 'positive')]

## neg_words = [({'pathetic': True}, 'negative')]

```
pos_words = []
neg_words = []
```

for pos_word in open(POS_WORDS_FILE, 'r').readlines()[35:]:
    pos_words.append(({pos_word.rstrip(): True}, 'positive'))

```
for neg_word in open(NEG_WORDS_FILE, 'r').readlines()[35:]:
neg_words.append(({neg_word.rstrip(): True}, 'negative'))

print ("First 5 positive words %s "  % pos_words[:5])
print ("First 5 negative words %s"  % neg_words[:5])

print ("Number of positive words %d" % len(pos_words))

print ("Number of negative words %d" % len(neg_words))

all_words_with_sentiment = pos_words + neg_words

print ("Total number of words %d" % len(all_words_with_sentiment))

from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier

classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(all_words_with_sentiment)


def to_dictionary(words):
return dict([(word, True) for word in words])


test_data = []


def predict_sentiment(text, expected_sentiment=None):
text_to_classify = to_dictionary(text.split())
result = classifier.classify(text_to_classify)
test_data.append([text_to_classify, expected_sentiment])
return result


POLARITY_DATA_DIR = os.path.join('polarity-data', 'rt-polaritydata')
POSITIVE_REVIEWS_FILE = os.path.join(POLARITY_DATA_DIR, 'rt-polarity-pos.txt')
NEGATIVE_REVIEWS_FILE = os.path.join(POLARITY_DATA_DIR, 'rt-polarity-neg.txt')

import collections

import nltk.classify
import nltk.metrics
#import nltk.metrics.scores
from nltk.util import LazyConcatenation, LazyMap

from nltk.util import LazyConcatenation, LazyMap
from decimal import *
from nltk.metrics.scores import (precision, recall)
from nltk.metrics import precision, recall
#from sklearn.metrics import precision_score


def run_sentiment_analysis_on_rt():
rt_positive_reviewers = open(POSITIVE_REVIEWS_FILE, 'r')

expected_pos_set = collections.defaultdict(set)
actual_pos_set = collections.defaultdict(set)

for index, review in enumerate(rt_positive_reviewers.readlines()):
    expected_pos_set['positive'].add(index)
    actual_sentiment = predict_sentiment(review, 'positive')
    actual_pos_set[actual_sentiment].add(index)

print ("Total Negative found in positive reviews %s" % 
len(actual_pos_set['negative']))

rt_negative_reviews = open(NEGATIVE_REVIEWS_FILE, 'r')

expected_neg_set = collections.defaultdict(set)
actual_neg_set = collections.defaultdict(set)

for index, review in enumerate(rt_negative_reviews.readlines()):
    expected_neg_set['negative'].add(index)
    actual_sentiment = predict_sentiment(review, 'negative')
    actual_neg_set[actual_sentiment].add(index)

print ("Total Positive found in negative reviews %s" % 
len(actual_neg_set['positive']))

print ('accuracy: %.2f' % nltk.classify.util.accuracy(classifier, test_data))
#print ('pos precision:', nltk.metrics.precision(refsets['pos'], testsets['pos']))
print ('pos precision: %.2f' % 
nltk.metrics.scores.precision(expected_pos_set['positive'], actual_pos_set['positive']))
print ('pos recall: %.2f' % 
nltk.metrics.scores.recall(expected_pos_set['positive'], actual_pos_set['positive']))
print ('neg precision: %.2f' % 
nltk.metrics.scores.precision(expected_neg_set['negative'], actual_neg_set['negative']))
print ('neg recall: %.2f' % 
nltk.metrics.scores.recall(expected_neg_set['negative'], actual_neg_set['negative']))


run_sentiment_analysis_on_rt()
```

Iam getting an error like:
AttributeError: module 'nltk.translate.metrics' has no attribute 'scores'

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
from nltk import precision
```

and invoke the precision method directly. It will work!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are calling the precision function incorrectly.
From the [docs](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.metrics.html) it seems like you should be using
`nltk.metrics.scores.precision` instead of `nltk.metrics.precision`. The same is true for recall.

Comment: But, still it is giving another error as:                                          
AttributeError: module 'nltk.translate.metrics' has no attribute 'scores'

Comment: Can you check you did not include the word  'translate' as the error seems to suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Just import the following.

```
from nltk import precision
```

and call the precision method directly, as given bellow.

```
nltk.precision(expected_neg_set['negative'], actual_neg_set['negative']))
```

It will work for sure!